# Power Bi Matrix Table "Go to the next level in hierarchy (Button)"

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I have an issue with drilling down the Metrix table "Go to the next level in the hierarchy (button)" is not making any sense to me as per my data.

Here is how my Data looks like.
[image]
Here is the default result of my Matrix Table.
[image]
Here is the level 1 result of hierarchy.
 [image]
Here is the level 2 result of hierarchy.
[image]
Here is the level 3 result of hierarchy.
[image]
By using "Go to the next level in the hierarchy (Button)" its simply adding up all the values by year, month and day as per our data I want to drill down using "Config" column as primary.

Eg.

```
Level 1
     config 1
            Year 2016            all values 
            Year 2017            all values 
Level 2
      config 1 
             Year 2016          
                  Month August         all values 
                  Month December     all values 
             Year 2017                                
                  Month August         all values 
                  Month December     all values 
Level 3                       

      config 1 
             Year 2016          
                  Month August 
                           Day 1     all values 
                           Day 2    all values 
                  Month December   
                           Day 1    all values 
                           Day 2    all values 
             Year 2017          
                  Month August 
                        Day 1     all values 
                        Day 2      all values 
                  Month December   
                        Day 1      all values 
                        Day 2       all values 

   So on config 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Previously  I Posted a Question regarding disable a "Go to the next level in the hierarchy (Button)"  or remove, as per the answer I received it is builtin functionality it cant be removed or disabled.
Here is the Matrix table "Expand all down one level in the hierarchy (Button)" and it's really serving my purpose perfectly.
[image]
Is there any way I can drill down using "Go to the next level in the hierarchy (Button)" and I can achieve the same result as 
"Expand all down one level in the hierarchy (Button)".  or if you have any other suggestion I will really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour that you observe is the ordinary behaviour for the `Go to the next level in the hierarchy` and `Expand all down one level in the hierarchy` buttons. So the natural answer is to use the latter instead of the former.

That said, if you would like to create a hierarchy where the user can use `Go to the next level in the hierarchy` button and achieve your desired result then you should add some calculated columns:

```
Hierarchy Lvl 1 = [Config] & " - " & [Date].[Year]
Hierarchy Lvl 2 = [Config] & " - " & [Date].[Year] & ", " & [Date].[Month]
...
```

You would also probably want to create some Sort By columns for those to ensure they display correctly e.g.

```
Hierarchy Lvl 2 Sort = VALUE([Config] & [Date].[Year] & [Date].[MonthNo])
...
```

Personally, this seems a bit much effort to go to just to avoid clicking the `Expand all down one level in the hierarchy` button...